# Ionic Framework display dynamic value inside $ionicLoading

Tags: ionic-framework

How can I display a dynamic value inside of ionicLoading?
Here is my code to show `$ionicLoading`, the idea here is to display download progress:

```
$rootScope.updateProgress = 0;
$ionicLoading.show({
  template: 'Updating...' + $rootScope.updateProgress
});
```

And later in my code I update `$rootScope.updateProgress`'s value:

```
var iPecent = Math.round(downloadProgress.receivedBytes / downloadProgress.totalBytes * 100);
$rootScope.$apply(function () {
  $rootScope.updateProgress = iPecent;
});
```

However, `$rootScope.updateProgress`'s value is not reflected when `$ionicLoading` is displayed on the screen - just shows initial value of 0. If I log out `$rootScope.updateProgress`'s value it is reflecting current download progress.

Comment: Are you using file transfer plugin to download the file

Comment: Yes sir, file transfer plugin is used to download an update for my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me use [cordova-plugin-file-transfer](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) as an example:

```
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: 'downloading...'
    });
    $cordovaFileTransfer.download(source, filePath, options, trustAllHosts).then(function (result) {
        console.log('download successfully!');
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, function (err) {
        alert('download failed!' + err);
    }, function (progress) {
        var downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: "Downloaded：" + Math.floor(downloadProgress) + "%"
        });
        if (downloadProgress >= 100) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This works for me! Thanks @Tom. By any chance to you know what is the performance impact on the application if you call `$ionicLoadigng.show()` a hundred times to display percentage change?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was requested and added here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/699.

I haven't tested it, but based on the statement:

> Use $ionicLoading.show() while the loader is open with new content,
>   and it will update the content.

If you call `.show()` subsequent to a `$ionicLoading` already showing, it should update the content.. If this feature is in fact now part of Ionic, and you put in some sort of loop and delay routine, you should be able to achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am using show percentage of image uploading like 19%...

```
var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
  $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Uploading Start....' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded /evt.total) + '%',

         });
```

where **evt** is callback of progress method.